# Sylius, plugin skeleton not working

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm trying to run the demo plugin for Sylius as found here:
https://github.com/Sylius/PluginSkeleton

but when doing so I'm getting:

```
ChannelNotFoundException: Channel could not be found!   -
in D:\WebRoot\sylius\DemoPlugin\vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Component\Channel\Context\CompositeChannelContext.php at line 53
```

and

```
Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Channel could not be found!").
in D:\WebRoot\sylius\DemoPlugin\vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\ShopBundle\Resources\views\layout.html.twig at line 24
```

I'm running it on php 5.6, Windows 7, but as it's my first time working with sylius or symfony - i'm really in the deep here.

The /admin/ shows correctly the login form though

Removing the channel error in question:

```
{% block top %}
```

by removing the whole block - just ends up erroring on some other place

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind plugins is to use them inside a Sylius installation. 
I've not created one yet, but I think you could download Sylius into your machine and run

```
bin/console sylius:install
```

against the same database. This will create a channel and all needed data, which can be used by your plugin.

Comment: sylius is already installed and working - i'm having trouble with the default plugin skeleton. Currently most of the time when trying to work with the system I'm getting out of allowed memory errors, so at the moment I'm trying with a different PHP version